# Jquery Dom and functions in html body

Tags: jquery, dom, function, internet-explorer-7, multiple-browsers

I have `<script>...</script>` before my closing body tag here i have the usual

```
$(function() {
   function test(){
      alert("test");
   }
});
```

in my html i have input tags `<input type="text" onchange="test()" />`

I get an error of that test is undefined. I am trying to make IE7 call function `onchange` I had a whole solution working but since IE7 does not like `.change()` i am going to put `onchange` attributes within the inputs but now i have  this issue.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`test` is unknown because it is local to the anonymous function (the `ready` handler) and not exposed to the outside world. That function is simply a `ready` handler that gets called when the DOM of the page is ready. If you want to expose `test` you need to do something like this:

```
var eventHandlers = $(function() {
   function test() {
      alert("test");
   }

   return {test: test};
})();
```

This is a bit of overkill and only necessary if you are using the module pattern and using encapsulation. You can now use `eventHandlers.test()`. If encapsulation is not an issue, I recommend binding to jQuery within the `ready` handler:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#myInput").bind("change", function() {
      alert("test");
    });
});
```

You can also simply define the function as:

```
function test() {
  alert("test");
}
```

Which would be the easiest way. However, I recommend not mixing different ways of doing things. If you are using jQuery, stick to doing everything with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery, use jquery everywhere.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('input').bind('change',function(){
alert("hi");
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To use it in this way, you need it outside that scope, use **only** this, no `document.ready` wrap:

```
function test(){
  alert("test");
}
```

If you wrap it in a `document.ready` handler, it's only available in that scope, you need to declare the function outside for that.  However you can do this completely in jQuery as well, like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myElem" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myElem').change(function() {
    alert("test");
  });
});
//or, if you wanted the external function for another reason:
$(function() {
  $('#myElem').change(test);
});
function test(){
  alert("test");
}
```